# Multiline string as a value in Json

Tags: json

Given this Json

```
{
"myclass": {
    "studentname": "myname",
    "description": "Student has three more credits to complete\n
    he is taking maths\ n
    biology this semester "
 }
}
```

I get a Json parser exception for 'description' in jsonlint. Changing the description to accept an array is not an option for me.

Is there any way to define multiline in Json?

Answer (score 3):

`\n` is the only way. JSON isn't programming language and you can't tell it to concatenate string. It depends on context too.

## This will work

```
{
    "myclass": {
        "studentname": "myname",
        "description": "Student has three more credits to complete\nhe is taking maths\nbiology this semester"
     }
}
```

## This will not work

```
{
    "myclass": {
        "studentname": "myname",
        "description": "Student has three more credits to complete\n
                        he is taking maths\n
                        biology this semester"
     }
}
```

Comment: JSON editor throws an error as well. You cannot have literal line breaks in string literals.

Comment: Actually not, it's just about saving, open fresh and paste that JSON there. No errors.

Comment: When I paste it the right hand side does not update, so I have to assume that it doesn't work, even if it doesn't explicitly show an error.

Comment: Press button with right arrow. It's not auto updating.

Comment: I see... but it doesn't matter what the editor is doing. The error when loading clearly shows that `JSON.parse` doesn't like it, so it cannot be valid. [The JSON spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) also says *"Whitespace is not allowed within any token, except that space is allowed in strings."*

Comment: Well, lets consider 2nd example as not working then.

Comment: I have a very long string and writing it in a single line with \n makes it really clumsy. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Anuram How about doing it your way, then changing every breakline to `\n` and passing that string as JSON value?